# Uploading image from swift to java REST api

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have created a java Rest api using JAX-RS which is perfect so far for doing all of my database calls etc, I need to be able to upload an image however and store it on the server. I am not sure how to receive the image in Java. 

I am sending it in swift using Alamofire as a multipart request containing 1 string and the jpeg file.
This is how i would normally receive strings in my java web app:

```
@POST
@Path("/restFunction1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String restFunction1(@FormParam("userId") String userId) throws IOException 
{
    //do stuff with userId
}
```

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using (e.g. Jersey, RESTeasy)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@POST
@Path("/restFunction1")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String restFunction1(@FormDataParam("userId") String userId, @FormDataParam("image") InputStream image) {

   //Do something with userId and image

}
```

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>     
    <version>2.17</version> 
</dependency>
```